# How do I solve the following equality-constrained quadratic program?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

I am trying to minimize:
$$(x_1-k_1)^2 + (x_2-k_2)^2 + (x_3-k_3)^2 +\ldots+ (x_n-k_n)^2$$

subject to following equality:
$$B = 1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4+\ldots+x_n.$$

Is there  a closed form solution for this?   I found the  case where $n=2$ using Lagrange multipliers and could do the same for case $n=3$, but does anyone see a simple solution?

Wikipedia gives [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints) solution, but I'm not sure if the matrix has an inverse so I'm weary of going down that route.  Also inverting matrix takes some computer time and may not be feasible for solving different instances of the problem thousands of times.

Also, I put $B$ above as a constant, which it is, but I'm interested in the case where $B = (1+k_1)\times(1+k_2)\times\ldots\times(1+k_n)$, but I'm not sure if that makes the problem easier.  My intuition is that it does not and just complicates things.

Comment: welcome to MSE, please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) to have a readable formate of your question.

Comment: The matrix has an inverse because it is $I_n$.

Answer (score 1):

We have a quadratic program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|\mathrm{x} - \mathrm{k}\|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & 1_n^T\mathrm{x} = c\end{array}$$

where $c = -1 + \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n (k_i+1)$. Using a Lagrange multiplier,

$$\mathcal{L} (x,\lambda) := \frac{1}{2}\|\mathrm{x} - \mathrm{k}\|_2^2 + \lambda (1_n^T \mathrm{x} - c)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish,

$$\nabla_x \mathcal{L} = \mathrm{x} - \mathrm{k} + \lambda 1_n = 0_n \qquad \qquad 1_n^T \mathrm{x} = c$$

Hence,

$$1_n^T \mathrm{x} - 1_n^T \mathrm{k} + \lambda 1_n^T 1_n = 0_n$$

and

$$\lambda = \dfrac{1_n^T \mathrm{k} - c}{n}$$

Thus, the minimum is attained at

$$\mathrm{x} = \mathrm{k} + \left(\dfrac{c - 1_n^T \mathrm{k}}{n}\right) 1_n$$

and the minimum is

$$\|\mathrm{x} - \mathrm{k}\|_2^2 = \left\|\left(\frac{c - 1_n^T \mathrm{k}}{n}\right) 1_n \right\|_2^2 = \frac{\left(c - 1_n^T \mathrm{k}\right)^2}{n}$$

Comment: $\lambda(1_n^Tx-c)$ won't work for an equality constraint. You need something that is an increasing function of the modulus so you get a minimum at 0.

Comment: @mathreadler I don't think so.

Comment: The term has no minimum at all, it's a plane that can get arbitrarily much negative the lower the mean value of x is. It could maybe be useful if you had an inequality constraint, to encourage (increasingly large negative values in the allowed area), but for an equality it won't work.

Comment: @mathreadler I have no idea what you're talking about. This is a QP with a linear equality constraint. Using a Lagrange multiplier is enough. It seems to me that you don't understand the difference between hard constraints and soft constraints.

Comment: Yes using a multiplier is enough, but that choice of function won't work unless the problem you are trying to solve has an **in**equality constraint. It's trivial really. Pretend you remove the function to minimize and accept any point on the equality constraint. Then minimizing $\lambda(1_n^Tx-c)$ is not gonna get you anywhere near the equality constraint, but it would if you had for example $\lambda\|1_n^Tx-c\|$ or $\lambda(1_n^Tx-c)^2$.

Comment: @mathreadler Won't work? The minimizer I found **does** satisfy the given equality constraint.

Comment: I'm with @RodrigodeAzevedo on this one. This is, in fact, a rather trivial equality constrained least squares problem, well known to have a closed-form solution obtained via Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the reasoning for the downvote for this answer in particular? I can understand the downvote for the other one.

Answer (score -2):

You can rewrite the constraint as:

$$0= 1-B +\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$

and then turn it into a cost function:

$$\lambda\left\|1-B+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right\|_2$$

If we want to we can rewrite this with matrices, $\bf 1$ being the column vector full of ones:

$$\min_{\bf x} \left\{ \|{\bf x}-{\bf k}\|_2 + \lambda\|1-B+{\bf 1}^T{\bf x}\|_2\right\}$$

You will probably get better faithfulness to the constraint if you solve a sequence of linear problems using  for example [**iterated reweighting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) approach replacing the 2-norm with another norm for the constraint term:

$$\min_{\bf x} \left\{ \|{\bf x}-{\bf k}\|_2 + \lambda\|1-B+{\bf 1}^T{\bf x}\|_k\right\}$$

you could aim for different $k$, but I think $k=1$ would be a good choice.

---

**EDIT** I erroneously claimed that 1-norm term in this case would be the Lasso method, but as pointed out below in comments, in that case the 1-norm is of course applied on the $\bf x$ vector alone. Even as the constraint is in fact a scalar the $k$ norm is **still relevant** as the deviation for the constraint would be punished differently from the terms in the least-squares term.

Comment: Why are you taking the $2$-norm of a scalar?

Comment: Because I want to measure and regulate it's size. Isn't that usually why you take the norm?

Comment: Why not just take the square or the absolute value?

Comment: Because it fits better into the framework with matrices and vectors.

Comment: There simply is no reason to do this. The problem has an analytic solution.

Comment: That's not a correct form of the lasso, besides. In a proper lasso, the $1$-norm is applied to the raw variables $x$, not a linear function thereof. Furthermore, because that quantity is a scalar, the specific norm $k$ is *irrelevant*; in every instance it reduces to an absolute value. The problems with this answer are myriad and I would strongly recommend removing it.

Comment: Yes, you are right on the lasso claim. It was actually wrong.

Comment: $k$ is still irrelevant. For *any* $k$, $\|1-B+1^Tx\|_k=|1-B+1^Tx|$. It doesn't matter at all what $k$ you choose.